# Opening Native File Browser in android using the cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using the cordova 3.4.0 and trying to upload a file, using the file transfer and file api plugins given by cordova, but i am not able to open the file browser window, in order to select the file to upload. How do i open the file browser window in android using the corodva

Answer (score 1):

I used an Input tag in my html, like so:

```
<input type='file' id='fileInput'>
```

And then when it is clicked on the Android device, I get a pop-up asking me which file browser I want to use.  My Galaxy S3 gives me seven choices (one of which is a downloaded app), and the Panasonic ToughPad I'm developing for gives me three (one of which is the same downloaded app I have on the phone).

I do not know if it is possible to get it to automatically select one in particular - for me, choosing a file manually is supposed to be a temporary need, as eventually the app is supposed to load specific files automatically.